# Advertising id is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 even after adding AD_ID permission to the manifest

Tags: android

I have targeted my android app to API 33. Also, as mentioned in the behavioural changes in Android13 doc I have added the following permission to the App's Manifest file.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

When I run the app and fetch the Google advertising id, I am still getting 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, whereas the documentation says you will only get zeroes if you have not added the permission in the manifest.

Also, I have not disabled app personalisation.

Following is my code to fetch the advertising id:

```kotlin
fun getAdvertisingIdInfo(context: Context): AdInfo {
        check(Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) { "Cannot be called from the main thread" }
        try {
            val pm = context.packageManager
            pm.getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", 0)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
        val connection = AdvertisingConnection()
        val intent = Intent("com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.service.START")
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gms")
        if (context.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
            return try {
                val adInterface = AdvertisingInterface(connection.binder)
                AdInfo(adInterface.id, adInterface.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled(true))
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                throw exception
            } finally {
                context.unbindService(connection)
            }
        }
        throw IOException("Google Play connection failed")
    }
```

Kindly note, I have only made one change, i.e. I have added the permission

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with following attribute in uses-permission tag

```xml
tools:node="remove"
```

Basically this removes the permission when merging Manifests. You can remove this and you should be able to fetch the advertising id